# Getting URL parameters with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is my current rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

three lines to do basically the same thing. Is there a way I can clean this up a bit? Is there one line that will accomplish this?

Also, Is there a way to pull multiple variables from a single url string? So if I had something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com?page=foo&id=123&color=red
```

how would I convert it to this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page/foo/id/123/color/red
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(cat|post|page)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

because `jacek_K` to you  one part, I give you answer of second part :
to rewrite this URL(http://www.mysite.com/page/foo/id/123/color/red), use this:

```
RewriteRule ^page\/([^/\.]+)\/id\/(\d+)\/color\/([^/\.]+)   index.php?page=$1&id=$2&color=$3 [L]
```